# How to get the user input with in the custom endpoint of Amazon Alexa

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

Is there a way to actually get the user utterance in an endpoint connected to a Amazon Alexa skill ?

Example if a user says within my skill:

User: "What is the best perfume?"

In the endpoint function i want a way to get that phrase.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a built-in slot `AMAZON.SearchQuery` for capturing less predictable input from the user. From the documentation:

> As you think about what users are likely to ask, consider using a built-in or custom slot type to capture user input that is more predictable, and the AMAZON.SearchQuery slot type to capture less-predictable input that makes up the search query.

But if possible try to create custom slots.
Also you can not use more than one `AMAZON.SearchQuery` slot per intent.

> Make sure that your skill uses no more than one AMAZON.SearchQuery slot per intent. The Amazon.SearchQuery slot type cannot be combined with another intent slot in sample utterances.

You can see more details at following [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#amazonsearchquery).

Comment: This is not what i need since i have already implemented it with SearchQuery but the problem with that is that you will always need a static word with that ... like "Find [anything goes here ]" and you cannot have the SearchQuery by itself.